# iOS: UILocalNotification array greater than 64 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

When my app closes or enters the background I run a function to schedule the `UILocalNotification`s.

The documentation states as follows:

> An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.

Does this mean I can just schedule all the notifications I want and the system will work out the appropriate 64 for me?

The reason I have doubts is that when ever I run the following I still see 100+ entries:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Print the total number of notifications scheduled
    println(UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications.count)
    // Clear the notification queue once they re-start the application. They will be rescheduled upon next exit
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
}
```

So even after I've exit the application and restart it there are still 100+ notifications and the system doesn't appear to have "discards the rest".

Comment: Anyone have some experience with this?